# Legends overlapping the plots in Rstudio

Tags: r, plot, graph, legend, legend-properties

I am trying to plot an image and then overlay a legend on its top. The legend is covering the plot and I am not able to adjust it using different parameters like `cex, lty, etc`.

```
plot(cov16_2ms04h$unqC_Sp, cov16_2ms04h$unqC_My, log="xy",
 col=(cov16_2ms04h$binom_q<0.001)+1,
 ylab="Haplotype B Count", xlab="Haplotype A Count")
abline(0,1,col="grey")
legend("topleft",c("No significant imbalance","Significant imbalance"),pch=c(10,10),col=c(1,2), cex = 0.5)
```

is giving me plot as:

[image: Observed plot]

**But, I want something like:**

[image: Expected plot]

Thanks,

Comment: please make your code chunk [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried enlarge the size of the plot before overlying a legend? I tried you legend code, the legend was perfect on the plot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with R-studio because the size of the output plot is determined by the costumized size of the pane.

**To plot the results directly to a pdf or a png file the following can be done.**

```
# plotting directly on pdf or png - select the required one
pdf("my_plot.pdf", height=6, width=6)
png("my_plot.png", width = 4, height = 4,
    units = 'in', res = 300)

plot(cov16_2ms04h$unqC_Sp, cov16_2ms04h$unqC_My, log="xy",
     col=(cov16_2ms04h$binom_q<0.001)+1,
     ylab="Haplotype B Count", xlab="Haplotype A Count")

abline(0,1,col="grey") # draw abline

legend("topleft",c("No significant imbalance","Significant imbalance"),
   pch=c(1,1),col=c(1,2), cex = 0.75)  # add legend

dev.off() # close the plot
```

**The output then comes as:**

[image]

Thanks,